# NetBeans code synchronisation

Tags: netbeans, synchronization

How can I sync code between my pc and my laptop. I'm using NetBeans for developing most of my projects. Now, I upload .zip ( or use dropbox ), but it is so annoying always to make a new project in NetBeans and add the source. Can't I just save the project on my PC and the project automatically synchronise to my laptop?

Comment: It appears that it's also possible to sync NetBeans projects between multiple computers using Dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's time for you to use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [SubVersioN](http://subversion.apache.org/) or [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_Systemhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_Systemhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System),  and possibly [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

All these versioning systems and project management system (Maven) are supported by NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Is it possible to set up automatic synchronization using any of those versioning systems?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to use [Revision (source) Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)

There are plenty of free SVN services out there (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/free-online-private-svn-repositories )

Working with SVN through netbeans is a breeze.